# New chain and cassette makes cycling much more difficult

Tags: chain, cassette, hills

I had a new chain and cassette fitted yesterday. But today, hills which I could easily climb two days ago are now horrendously challenging. What was a pleasure has just become a nightmare. Why is this happening? What should I do?

The bike is a Specialized Tricross, about 4 years old. Never had new rear cassette before, but has had new front cogs, new derailleur, and previously one new chain. The bike appears to work OK when on a rack. See my comment below, please.

Edit. Update with new information:
Counted teeth as follows: front 50/30, rear 28/11. There are eight rear cogs. The front cogs were changed a year ago, so I have been accustomed, and the shop advised at the time, original size was now obsolete. It would seem that the rear cassette changed ten days ago is a different size to original, and it seems this may explain my struggling to ride with same positioning of gears as previously. Each of the numbers I have quoted here I counted twice. Seems a different size of cassette was fitted

Comment: Is this problem only present when climbing, or is your downhill-speed also impeded? How does "horrendously challenging" manifest itself, is it some kind of extra resistance, or is it something like cranks turning too slowly? Do you feel extra resistance when you have your wheel off the ground (bike upside down or suspended somehow)? Do your wheels turn freely when off the ground? Please add some of these details, perchance you will answer your question yourself when you try to determine the answers to my questions...

Comment: Does the new cassette have identical gear ratios to the old one? Hybrid bikes often come with a cassette whose biggest cog is much bigger than the next one (I forget what Shimano calls this; the informal term is a "granny gear"), but these often get replaced with a cassette with closer ratios.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Shimano MegaRange is what you are thinking of

Comment: My first guess would be that the rear derailer is improperly adjusted and you are unable to access the larger (easier) sprockets. You should return to the shop for proper adjustment.

Comment: @DanielRHicks agree - OP should take bike back to where the chain and cassette was fitted and ask 'what's wrong?' or 'what changed?'

Comment: If you can edit your question to include the approx. year along with the make and model we may be able to help you determine if your new cassette is identical to the old.

Comment: Extremely grateful to all who have commented. I cycled early today Sunday UK time, and did a series of serious (by my standard) hills. I think the new parts have returned the bike to its original 'gearing', and I find if I use a gear one or two steps lower, it works OK. I think. I'm guessing the previous chain and cassette were so shot, the 'gearing' had moved so's I could use a higher gear. I guess. Does this make sense to anyone? Today was easier, and I'm thinking I just need to adjust / let the materials 'bed in'. Comments on this still welcomed.

Comment: Someone should be able to find some tricross original specs, please can you count the teeth on the largest cassette sprocket, as well as the smallest chainring, and report back? comparing these with the original spec should be an objective answer. Are you currently able to get the chain into the lowest possible gear?

Comment: @swifty the Tricross came with Sora 9 speed 12/27 and 50/34 chainring

Comment: Just to point out: There should be no “bed in” required. Drivetrain friction goes down very slightly after after a few hundred km, but we are talking <1% losses here.

Comment: @Swifty Counted teeth as follows: front 50/30, rear 28/11. There are eight rear cogs. The front cogs were changed a year ago, so I have been accustomed, and the shop advised at the time, original size was now obsolete. It would seem that the rear cassette changed ten days ago is a different size to original, and it seems this may explain my struggling to ride with same positioning of gears as previously. Each of the numbers I have quoted here I counted twice. Seems a different size of cassette was fitted.

Comment: I can't call the shop today (Sunday) as they are closed to check it was a new cassette fitted, but I'll try to visit them this week (it's not really nearby) to check the bike and check if the cassette is different. I am extremely grateful to all who have commented, and sorry I've been so slow in counting and coming back to you all. I welcome any further comments, of course.

Comment: I tried to @ everyone who commented, but it didn't work. Hope you can red, and thanks to all.